# Apps made in swift 2.2 uploaded to The App Store will run on ios 10?

Tags: ios, app-store, ios10

If my app is now on the `App Store` which was developed in `Swift 2.2`, will it run on `iOS 10.x`?  Or do I have to update my code to `Swift 3`?

Comment: Guaranteed it is support in iOS 10, but in future if you need the upgradation in Syntax in Swift then go for Xcode 8 .x and above

Comment: see this also for additional https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=36

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will run on `iOS 10`, but it's better to properly test your application by using `iOS 10.x betas` to get surety that all the features of your application are working great without any crash or bugs.